# How to user if condition in yii2 gridview active button or deactive botton show on gridview

Tags: yii, yii2-advanced-app

How  to user if condition in yii2 gridview  active button or deactive button show on gridview

```
     <div class="report-index">
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}",
     'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
       'username',
        'email',
        'status',
     [
    'attribute'=>'created_at',
    'format' => ['date', 'php:d.m.Y'],
    ],
    'active',
      [
      'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
      'header' => 'Action',
      'template' => '{view}{delete}',
      'buttons' => [
        'view' => function ($url, $model,$key) {

            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">           </span>', $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'),
            ]);
        },

         'delete' => function ($url, $model,$key) {

            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Delete'),
            ]);
        },

      ],

     ],

    ],

]); ?>

    <div id="custom-pagination">
    <?php

      echo LinkPager::widget([
'pagination' => $pages,
     );

    ?>
```

How  to user if condition in yii2 gridview  active button or deactive button show on gridview i use two button when active is 1 show green button if active record 0 show red button

how  to user if condition in yii2 gridview  active button or deactive button show on gridview i use two button when active is 1 show green button if active record 0 show red button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have add a anonymous function to `value` with signature `function($model, $key, $index)`    [reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#renderTableRow()-detail)

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}",
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'username',
        'email',
        'status',
        [
            'attribute'=>'created_at',
            'format' => ['date', 'php:d.m.Y'],
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'active',
            'header'=>'Status',
            'filter' => ['Y'=>'Active', 'N'=>'Deactive'],
            'format'=>'raw',    
            'value' => function($model, $key, $index)
            {   
                if($model->is_active == 'Y')
                {
                    return '<button class="btn green">Y</button>';
                }
                else
                {   
                    return '<button class="btn red">N</button>';
                }
            },
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header' => 'Action',
            'template' => '{view}{delete}',
            ...
```